# postgresql export database to xml

Tags: xml, postgresql, export, pgadmin-4

I've been trying recently to output my PostgreSQL database to XML using database_to_xml function. The command seems to work, because it is being processed for two minutes every time I try to use it, but I have no idea where to look for my output file. In PgAdmin, in the Query History, it says "Rows affected: -1", so I'm afraid it doesn't work as it should.

This is my full query statement:

```
SELECT database_to_xml('true', 'true', 'n')
```

Is this command enough or should I add something more to my query? Also, when reading the documentation, I've found three versions of it:

```
database_to_xml(nulls boolean, tableforest boolean, targetns text)
database_to_xmlschema(nulls boolean, tableforest boolean, targetns text)
database_to_xml_and_xmlschema(nulls boolean, tableforest boolean, targetns text)
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: It works fine with `psql`. Maybe you shouldn't use pgAdmin for large output like this. Perhaps `psql -Atq -c "<statement>"` and redirecting the output would be the best option.